Are questions on whether the author provided clarification on their intent on topic?
To clarify I am aware that questions about authorial intent are considered off topic but are questions structured such as "Has Gary Gygax provided clarification on what they meant by'You know the language of your alignment' in the D&D 1e core book through social channels or in further books?" off topic as well?
The question is technically a request to clarify the authors intent but from my understanding the reason we have that ban is because questions on author intent or RAI often elicit opinion based responses.

Questions about designer intent were declared on topic two years ago. (Voted to close as duplicate since this question is covered by the linked FAQ).
